# Use a vector in method parameter in Java

Tags: java, vector

I want to pass a vector and string in my method parameters, but I'm not sure how to do that. I know that for arrays you can do it like that:

```
public int[] array_oef5 (int[] nummers) {
```

But I have never used this for a vector. Here's my program:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Oef7 {

    public static boolean vContains (String s,  Vector<String> v) {
        boolean b = false;
        System.out.println(s);
        System.out.println(v);
        return b;
    }
}
```

I don't get any error with it, but when I open the program in BlueJ, I don't know how I have to enter the values (in arrays it's like: {"Tuna","Fish"}. But how is it in a Vector?

Comment: `Vector` is obsolete and anyways you should code to the interface, i.e. use `List<String>` instead. Have a look at the [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/list.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html). You could, for example, use the `add` method to append a new string to the end of the vector:

```
v.add("Tuna");
v.add("Fish");
```

Answer (score 0):

Unlike arrays, you cannot create a new Vector and put values into it in one single statement.

You will have to create a vector and add the values one by one:

```
Vector<String> v = new Vector();
v.add("Tuna");
v.add("Fish");
```

Then you can call your method `vContains` by passing the newly created vector object:

```
vContains("Tuna", v);
```

Please also note that if you want to print the contents of the vector, you cannot simply call `System.out.println(v)` but you will have to iterate over its contents, like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) 
{
    System.out.println(v.get(i));
}
```

Comment: Actually, you can do it in a single statement: `Vector<String> v = new Vector<>(Arrays.asList("Tuna", "Fish"));`. Also, `System.out.println(v);` works well because `Vector` extends `AbstractCollection` which provides a sensible [`toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#toString()) implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `List` instead of `Vector`.

A historical note; List replaced Vectors as the preferred variable type in 1998.

```
class Oef7{
    public static boolean vContains (String s,  List<String> v){
        return v.indexOf(s) >= 0;
    }
}
```

You can pass a List like this.

```
boolean isIn = vContains("Hi", Arrays.asList("Hi", "World"));
```

Comment: The thing is i have to do it in that way for school, thanks for the history lesson tho xp

Comment: @TinaXx I should have added, that it is valid to use Vector if you have no choice. ;)  However it is also worth learning how it should be done if you did have a choice. Note: `Vector` also has `indexOf` as it is a `List`